# SSO and using Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on

I'm making an app that I want to sign into EVE Online using their SSO. I have managed to make Windows start an application when the browser receives the specified link (eve://sso).

This concept require a new application to start at the request, then from that talking to my running application.

Can someone lead me on a path on how I can make the running application receive the callback instead of starting an application?

Comment: Make the exe associated with eve:// look for an existing instance of itself, if it finds one have it communicate the new URI via some form of IPC or take advantage of the handy VB class that does this for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance.aspx

Comment: Right after posting the question I found this: https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/842 that might be exactly what I need. Hoping there is an even simpler solution though.